# array of objects of a class

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
class test{
    int a;
    char b;
public:
    test()
    {
        cout<<"\n\nDefault constructor being called";
    }
    test(int i,char j)
    {
        a=i;
        b=j;
        cout<<"\n\nConstructor with arguments called";
    }
};
int main()
{
    test tarray[5];
    test newobj(31,'z');
};
```

In the above code snippet can we initialize values to `tarray[5]`?

Comment: For sure, the elements you initialize will call the appropriate constructor, and the ones you left uninitialized will be instantiated by default constructor.

Answer (score 7):

```
test  tarray[5] = {test(1, 2), test(), test(5, 6), test()};
```

The fifth element will be initialized with default constructor.

```
//here length of array will be inferred from number of initializers,
//   so it's going to be 4
test  tarray[] = {test(1, 'a'), test(), test(5, 'b'), test()};
```

Comment: tarray is an object of class test and it has its own int a and char b.how can we intializa the character

Comment: @anurag18294: tarray is an array of `test` s, not an instance of `test`.  However, its members are instances of `test`.  In other words, there is no `tarray.b`, only `tarray[0].b`, `tarray[1].b`, etc.

Comment: can we intialize it in this manner
test tarray[5]={test(1,'a'),test(3,'b'),test(5,6),test(),test(4,'s')};

Comment: @anurag, sure, whatever `test` constructor can handle.